# How to give styles to the data grid row according to the value in the column in mvvm pattern?

Tags: wpf

I am developing wpf application in mvvm pattern.In my application, i used data grid to represent the data.my requirement is "Giving the different styles to the row based on the column value that is coming from the database". For that, I used data triggers to give styles to the rows.But in data triggers,we give only one style.I want different styles for one data trigger.The value comparison operators used for my requirement are '>','<' and '='.
Can anyone give me the solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [datatemplateselector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).Check the below post for more

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/08/13/datagrid-part-2-show-me-some-code.aspx